# C# Soap with Attachments | CustomEncoder mapping to CustomType

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

i have a webservice, which is giving me some soap-with-attachments messages.
since that's not supported in wcf, i wrote a custom encoder based on this one: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wcfswaencoder

it's receiving and the decoding the messages correctly, however the return types don't match.
I generated the service reference based on the wsdl as follows:

[image]

The encoder doesn't know the type of course, i'm overwriting ReadMessage(...) to return a message object:
public override Message ReadMessage(System.IO.Stream stream, int maxSizeOfHeaders, string contentType)

The returned Message has the attachment data as Message.Properties property, and the xml part as the message.

after calling the webservice method, when debugging ReadMessage(), he's just jumping straight to the result, so somewhere in between the custom type must have been deserialized.

The problem is the deserialization is not correct.
The DataEntity + the name + the contentType are correct.
But attachments are not correctly mapped to the DataEntity.Value.

Is there a way to build the result object myself from the Message object?
Or how do i have to build the Message object so that it's correctly mapped to the custom result type?

EDIT:
As suggested by jdweng, i derived from IXmlSerializable and i get the message which i can now read however i want.
Now the problem is, the message looks like this:
[image]

i have no idea what to do with the [object Object].
that should be the message, but how was that serialized?

Comment: I think you need a Custom X,ml Serializer.  Normally the input/output is XmlReader/XmlWriter which are streams and can be cast to a BinaryReader/BinaryWriter.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng and where could i plug that into the messageEncoder?
actually the returned message-object is fine.
i thought i would need a converter from message to my custom type.
so it's xml -> message -> result
and i need to customize the conversion message -> result

Comment: XmlReader and XmlWriter inherit the base class stream.  So serialize is from c# classes to a stream, and deserialize is from a stream to c# classes.  So I think you can bypass the XML and go directly between classes and stream by casting.

Comment: XmlReader doesn't inherit stream

Comment: Your right.  should of referred to following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization